# append-only databases?

Tags: logging, plot, rrdtool

i need to log some data from multiple processes concurrently (on Windows), to be plotted and whatnot later.  rrdtool is great, but i don't have data at regular intervals.  what else is there?

**edit**:

basically, i don't have "time-series data", so the rrdtool tag may be a red herring.

the data i want to log is tuples *(url, requested at, processing time)* and *(sql query, issued at, processing time)*, for the purposes of monitoring and analysis of a web application.  a popular URL may be requested by several users at the same time, other URLs will have few accesses over unpredictable periods of time.  there's no sampling frequency i could apply this early in the processing pipeline.

i already log this data, into a SQL database.  which is kinda stupid because its features inapplicable to my situation make it needlessly slow and increase the risk of the log missing an entry here or there.  so i was hoping to find something like rrdtool, only without this feature ([rrd-beginners](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrd-beginners.en.html)):

> Other databases get updated when values are supplied. The RRDtool database is structured in such a way that it needs data at predefined time intervals. If it does not get a new value during the interval, it stores an UNKNOWN value for that interval. So, when using the RRDtool database, it is imperative to use scripts that run at regular intervals to ensure a constant data flow to update the RRDtool database.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for regular intervals in rrdtool. The data must just be continuous. RRDtool will see to the re-sampling internally.

Comment: thx for chiming in.  see the edited question for clarifications.